# How to return array of sheets with excel function vba?

Tags: excel, vba, function, return, worksheet

i need to create a function that return an array of worksheet to use this :
Sheets(fctListeFeuillesArray()).Select

The function works fine but i don't know what type i need to write for the input and the return :

This is the function :

```vb
Public Function fctListeFeuillesArray() As Worksheet
 Dim ar1() As Worksheet
....

Set fctListeFeuillesArray = ar1
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```vb
Public Function fctListeFeuillesArray() As Variant

Dim ar1 As Variant
ReDim ar1(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'if ws.name like "*xxx" then 
       i = i + 1
       ar1(i) = ws.Name
    'end if
Next

'redim preserve ar1(i)     ' in case you activate the if-part

fctListeFeuillesArray = ar1
End Function
```

Maybe you have to add some criteria to the `for each` loop in case you don't want to add all sheets. Then you have to add a `redim preserve ar1(i)` after the loop.